# is.null or empty or missing value in numeric vector and character vector

Tags: r, review, identification

I'm in trouble with the code that will give accurate information about my blank or different types of data.

[image]

The codes I wrote to recognize the data did not give what I wanted.

```
a= sapply(x, class),
s= sapply(x, function(y) length(y)),
d= sapply(x, function(y) length(unique(y))),
f= colSums(is.na(x)),
g= round(colSums(is.na(x)) / nrow(x) * 100, 2),
h= sapply(x, function(y) any(is.nan(y))),
j= sapply(x, function(xy) sum(missing(xy))),
k= sapply(x, function(xz) sum(is.null(xz))),
l= sapply(x, function(y) sum(y=="[[:blank:]]")), #if (is.double(y)==T | is.integer(y)==T )  else 0),
m= sapply(x, function(y) if (is.numeric(y)==TRUE) min(y,na.rm = TRUE) else 0),
n= sapply(x, function(y) if (is.numeric(y)==TRUE) max(y,na.rm = TRUE) else 0)
```

what code should i use here?

Comment: Hi. I think you need to be more specific about what your issue is and what you want to do. Also please include a reproducible example if you can.When others can easily reproduce the issue you're running into, they'll better be able to help.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the `janitor` package? https://github.com/sfirke/janitor

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data using `dput(head(x,10))`?

Comment: Hi, I want to see the available data in each column. so I want to recognize the arguments that don't work.

Comment: I used the above codes as part of a function for data discovery, but none of them gave the correct result.